# MySQL National Stock Numbers (NSN) for identification of assets

Tags: mysql, syntax

In MySQL are there any restrictions (and/or) practical reasons against using a numbering system similiar to the National Stock Number format as follows 3728-01-234-5678 (this format includes the use of the hyphen between groups of characters within the structure)

Would this require the use of a specific engine like InnoDB

A newbie student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issues I see with this is that you will have to implement your own [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) and store this in a [string/varchar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) type fields.

*This might take more space than a normal auto increment.*

Comment: astander, Thank you for the discussion... I will attemt to follow thru with this advice!
sammysmall